# What softwares are required for using mysql in java program

Tags: jdbc

i want to use mysql as a database in my java program. What softwares must be preinstalled in my system to make use of it ? Please give thelist and links to the softwares

Also let me know the installation procedure

Comment: You need the MySQL Connector for Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think using NetBeans IDE would be the best to code in Java!
Get it from sun Microsystems web page.......
Install mysql server client on your machine via Oracle's webpage!
Use "mysql connector" jar file reference in your project.....
Execute queries after making the connection to the desired database!

Happy Coding!

Comment: NetBeans has nothing to do with it. -1